# is there a mirror of the Opa API documentation?

Tags: opa

The api documentation seems to be down right now:

http://doc.opalang.org/api/index.html

Does anyone know if there's a mirror?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it has been fixed.

Comment: It seems to be down again. Any plans to add a mirror for the docs?

Comment: This problem seems to be recurrent again and OPA's people don't seem to care that much, even when asking for it on the official OPA forum